# Java Xpath query

Tags: java, xml, xpath, tags

How can I use Java Xpath to get the value of 2nd "c" tag d and f as 2

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>1</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>2</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
            <c type="h">
            <d>v</d>
            <f>d</f>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>

 { 
    DocumentBuilderFactory dBFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder dB = dBFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dB.parse(url);     
  System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
  XPathExpression expr=null;
  String text= null;
  expr= xpath.compile("//a/b/c[@type='lol']/d/text()");// this gets the first value
  text = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
     }
```

How can I use Java Xpath to get the value of 2nd "c" tag d and f as 2

Comment: Your question could do with a tweak or two - the XML endtag is wrong and the sample xpath says "b" instead of d. Good answer below, though, I learnt something today ;]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
//a/b/c[@type='lol'][2]/d/text()
```

Comment: Thanks , i found the solution myself too.. just now..  I came to add my solution , u(@ Kirill)  had already put the solution :)