# how can is get the nodelist of child node using xpath dom java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, jxl

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>1</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>2</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="h">
            <d>v</d>
            <f>d</f>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dBFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dB = dBFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dB.parse(url);     
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

how can is get the nodelist of child node i.e i need to get the child nodes of "b"(nodelist which has 3 "c" nodes )..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Xpath query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109428/java-xpath-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) and then write

```
List<Element> elements = $(doc).find("b").children().get();
```

Or with DOM:

```
// Beware, this list also contains the blank text nodes around the <c/> elements,
// if your document is formatted.
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("b").item(0).getChildNodes();
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to further traverse your DOM document (i.e. get the child nodes of `"c"` as you mention in your comments, then I really recommend jOOX:

```
// This will find all "c" elements, and then return all children thereof
$(doc).find("c").children();

// This will return "d", "f", "d", "f", "d", "f":
List<String> tags = $(doc).find("c").children().tags();

// This will return "1", "2", "2, "2", "v", "d":
List<String> texts = $(doc).find("c").children().texts();
```

Doing the same with DOM will become quite verbose:

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();

NodeList c = doc.getElementsByTagName("c");
for (int i = 0; i < c.getLength(); i++) {
  if (c.item(i) instanceof Element) {
    NodeList children = c.item(i).getChildNodes();

    for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
      if (children.item(j) instanceof Element) {
        elements.add((Element) children.item(j));
        tags.add(((Element) children.item(j)).getTagName());
        texts.add(children.item(j).getTextContent());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2 (please be more specific with your future questions...!)**: With XPath, do this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//c/*");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(
  document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: suppose i want the child nodes of "c" ? Sorry i have a complex xml where i have to get the child nodes , grand child nodelist(child has child and its child nodelist) ... the code helps and can i say doc.getElementsByTagName("c").item(0).getchildnode() ;

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need it using xpath only .... i am 70 % done with my code.. with very little time left i cannot go for the new approch..

Comment: Apart from the XPath tag, there's nothing in your question indicating so... Can you please at least update your question accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using XPath

```
String xmlSource = "<a>" +
                    "<b>" +
                        "<c type='lol'>" +
                            "<d>1</d>" +
                            "<f>2</f>" +
                        "</c>" +
                        "<c type='lol'>" +
                            "<d>2</d>" +
                            "<f>2</f>" +
                        "</c>" +
                        "<c type='h'>" +
                            "<d>v</d>" +
                            "<f>d</f>" +
                        "</c>" +
                    "</b>" +
                "</a>";

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); 
String expression = "/a/b/c";   

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource));             
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue());    
}
```

You will need to import the following

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
```